# Product List Grid only displaying 6 products

Tags: product-list

I'm currently using Magento 1.13 and am using this to display products from this specific category id:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="" category_id="224" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

By default, it is only show 6 products, though I have more than 6 in that category.  Is there a way to remove the limit?  Where is the limit being generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento doesn't have limit to show per category, they do have a limit per page that can be set in System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend.

Please ensure that

- Products has been assigned to the right category, this can be check by going to `Manage -> Category`, select the category and choose the Category Product tab.
- The product are enabled, not out-of-stock, and the visibility is set to Catalog or Catalog & Search
- Run re-index and flush the cache

All this information only apply if you are using `catalog/product/list.phtml` from Magento core template, your customised template could have different logic.